# how to enter values in 2 identical tables in excel?

Tags: excel

I have table 1 on sheet 1 and the same table (table 2) on sheet 2. how to make it so that when entering values ​​into table 1, the same values ​​fall into table 2

Comment: If you want to use excel formula only then simply use `=Sheet1!A1` adjust range in case of you. Otherwise you have to use `VBA` macro. You can also use `=INDEX(Table1,ROW(1:1),COLUMN(A1))`

Comment: and if there are more than 2 tables, for example, on page 1 there are 3 tables (table 1,2,3), on page 2 table-1, on page 3 table-2, on page 4 table-3 and when filling out the table on page 2 it was also filled table-1 on page 1

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below links. Follow the steps if you find any problem then let us know
http://www.microknowledge.com/link-excel-data-across-multiple-sheets/
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-relationship-between-tables-in-excel-fe1b6be7-1d85-4add-a629-8a3848820be3

Comment: Do you got it. if it is helpful